# Unexpected output of cut command

Tags: ssh, command-line, cut

I am trying to convert the key value pair output of the script to csv file using the following commands.

```
cat config/password | ssh -tt -J support@$gateway support@$ip "$(<${base}/systemkv.sh)" 3>/dev/null | tee /tmp/log | cut -d ':' -f2 | paste -s -d ',' - | tee -a /tmp/output.csv
```

The above command just shows the last line or the last line overlaps with other lines.

The cut command works perfectly for the command below, but it does not allow the use of sudo command.

```
cat config/password | ssh -J support@$gateway support@$ip "$(<${base}/systemkv.sh)" 3>/dev/null | tee /tmp/log | cut -d ':' -f2 | paste -s -d ',' - | tee -a /tmp/output.csv
```

**Expected Output**

```
first:Sujit
last:Maharjan
Sujit,Maharjan
```

**Real Output**

```
first:Sujit
last:Maharjan
,Maharjan
```

Comment: When you say "overlaps with other lines" and indicate output that is missing data, the usual culprit are carriage returns in the original output. That seems to be the systemkv.sh script.  The 3rd line that it outputs would be the one to focus on.

Comment: Adding to Jeff Schaller's comment above. Try running `ssh ... | od -c`. That should show you the output broken down into individual characters. Compare this between the two variants of the SSH command that you have tested.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit seems to be the carriage return character. I deleted the \r by using.

```
ssh ... | tr -d '\r' | ...
```

The command is now working perfectly.

Thanks, @Jeff Schaller and @Haxiel for your help.

Comment: You might consider putting that `tr` as close to the problem as possible, perhaps inside the command substitution.